# easier way to get stdin-lines converted to "float/int" arrays in python

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, input, casting

I always want to learn better and shorter ways to code, so I have a pretty complicated input which I guess could be written way simpler:

I have an unknown size of float inputs and I want to turn every line into an array when the last input is a new line.

```
import sys
input_matrix = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line != '\n':
        str_input = line.split(" ")
        float_input = []
        for i in range(len(str_input)):
            float_input.append(float(str_input[i]))
        input_matrix.append(float_input)
    else:
        break
```

And the input is something like this:

```
2.0 9.0 3.2 0.1 2.0
10 19 2.0
18 20 1.0 1.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The builtin [`iter` has a second form](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) specifically for this usecase.

> One useful application of the second form of `iter()` is to read lines
>   of a file [or stdin] until a certain line is reached.

Using this you can achieve the same result with a single list-comprehension.

```
input_matrix = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in iter(input, '')]

print(input_matrix)
```

#### Output

```
2.0 9.0 3.2 0.1 2.0
10 19 2.0
18 20 1.0 1.5

[[2.0, 9.0, 3.2, 0.1, 2.0], [10.0, 19.0, 2.0], [18.0, 20.0, 1.0, 1.5]]
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Comment: this is plain awesome, I was looking for exactly this type of answer! thx so much

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>import sys
>>>input_matrix = []
>>> while True:
...   line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
...   if not line:
...     break
...   input_matrix.append(map(float, line.split()))
...
2.0 9.0 3.2 0.1 2.0
10 19 2.0
18 20 1.0 1.5

>>> input_matrix
[[2.0, 9.0, 3.2, 0.1, 2.0], [10.0, 19.0, 2.0], [18.0, 20.0, 1.0, 1.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a small list comprehension. It may save 2 lines in this code, but in big programs it can save quite a lot of line, and don't forget to import `sys` or it will show error. Here is the code:

```
import sys
input_matrix = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line != '\n':
        str_input = line.split(" ")
        float_input = [str_input[i] for i in range(len(str_input))]
        input_matrix.append(float_input)
    else:
        break
```